# How do I select fields in difference collections MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

One of my fields needs to hold a total score which it gets by adding the scores from a different collection (`Players`). Each player has a field for its scores. I understand that I could get the ids of each player but how would I only get the score field?

The structure is something like this:

```
db.players.insert({
 name: 'Bob',
 score: 30,
});

db.players.insert({
 name: 'Emily',
 score: 50,
});

db.totalscores.insert({
 total: "calculate score"*
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

That is called **projection**.

you can do a simple `find({your search critieria}, {field projection})`

example would be

```
db.players.find({},{score:1, _id:0})
```

this will return only score field.like this

```
{ "score" : 30 }
{ "score" : 50 }
```

but a nicer alternative would be to use aggregate and calculate the score directly

```
db.players.aggregate([ { 
    $group: { 
        _id: null, 
        total: { 
            $sum: "$score" 
        } 
    } 
} ] )
```

this will return

```
{ "_id" : null, "total" : 80 }
```

you can also get rid of the ID from the output by simply including a $project stage and setting _id to 0.

Comment: totalscores is a collection so I will have to insert the score into the total field.   I don't think I will be able to use aggregate for this

Comment: why not. capture that in a variable and use that to insert. otherwise you can use the other option i provided.

Comment: is there a way, I could use aggregate with many collections. For example if I wanted to get the score from the collection Team and add it to total. So total: $sum: '$playerscore' + $sum: '$teamscore'

Comment: you might have many players and each player belongs to a team i assume. now you can simply filter by team and get the sum of score of each individual player. is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: No they won't be linked as I just gave team as an example but I wanted to know if it was possible to add the values of fields that belong to different collections and then put this value in a new collection called totalscore

Comment: yes you can use $lookup for that. i will post a small sample here

Comment: db.people.aggregate([
{$lookup:
 {from:"companies",
 localField:"company_id",
 foreignField:"_id",
 as:"company"}},
 {$unwind:"$company"},
 {$project:{"first_name":1,"last_name":1,"job":1,"sector":"$company.sector","company":"$employer"}}])

here i am fetching the "sector" field from companies collection and remaining fields come from people collection. Do you know that with mongo 3.4 you can create views rather then creating actual collections.

Comment: if my answers were any helpful to you dont forget to upvote or accept :)

Comment: I want people to be able to use find() on totalscores

Comment: there should be some relation (common field) between total score and people in that case.

Comment: yes, totalscores will have fields playerscores and teamscores. playerscores will have a sum of all player scores and teamscores will have a sum of team scores.

Comment: Is this possible with one aggregate as it needs to access two collections and then put the values in another collections.

Comment: not with your current structure. i don't think so. because fields like scores are not good candidates to rely upon when doing lookup you will definitely end-up getting wrong results. is schema modification under your control ?

Comment: I do. in my javascript file I have the collection totalscores but I don't know how to put the value in the totalplayerscore field